# jslink on Tasks % Complete field

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server

I've tried some code from [Client-side rendering (JS Link) code samples](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Client-side-rendering-JS-2ed3538a) but I can't get that slider to work on edit form.

```
(function () {

// Create object that have the context information about the field that we want to change it's output render 
var percentCompleteFiledContext = {};
percentCompleteFiledContext.Templates = {};
percentCompleteFiledContext.Templates.Fields = {
    // Apply the new rendering for PercentComplete field on List View, Display, New and Edit forms
    "PercentComplete": { 
        "View": percentCompleteViewFiledTemplate,
        "DisplayForm": percentCompleteViewFiledTemplate,
        "NewForm": percentCompleteEditFiledTemplate,
        "EditForm": percentCompleteEditFiledTemplate
    }
};

SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(percentCompleteFiledContext);

})();

function percentCompleteViewFiledTemplate(ctx) {

var percentComplete = ctx.CurrentItem[ctx.CurrentFieldSchema.Name];
return "<div style='background-color: #e5e5e5; width: 100px;  display:inline-block;'> \
        <div style='width: " + percentComplete.replace(/\s+/g, '') + "; background-color: #0094ff;'> \
        &nbsp;</div></div>&nbsp;" + percentComplete;

}

function percentCompleteEditFiledTemplate(ctx) {

var formCtx = SPClientTemplates.Utility.GetFormContextForCurrentField(ctx);

// Register a callback just before submit.
formCtx.registerGetValueCallback(formCtx.fieldName, function () {
    return document.getElementById('inpPercentComplete').value;
});

return "<input type='range' id='inpPercentComplete' name='inpPercentComplete' min='0' max='100' \
        oninput='outPercentComplete.value=inpPercentComplete.value' value='" + formCtx.fieldValue + "' /> \
        <output name='outPercentComplete' for='inpPercentComplete' >" + formCtx.fieldValue + "</output>%";

}
```

I've tried it on an Office 365 SP site.
I think that 
    document.getElementById('inpPercentComplete') 
returns null 
Any ideas ?
Thank you

Sorin

Comment: What does ``document.getElementById('inpPercentComplete').value `` return in F12 Dev Tools when the EditForm is loaded?

Comment: <input type="text" value="50" id="PercentComplete_d2311440-1ed6-46ea-b46d-daa643dc3886_$NumberField" title="% Complete" size="11" class="ms-input" style="ime-mode : inactive">

Answer (score 2):

I copy / pasted your code and it seems to be working fine.

[image: Screenshot]

Things to check:

- Check if you have attached your JSLink file properly to the webpart. Follow the steps outlined here: [Article](http://www.idubbs.com/blog/2012/js-link-for-sharepoint-2013-web-partsa-quick-functional-primer/)
- If the above doesn't work, you can simply edit the page, add a content editor / script editor webpart **below** the EditForm webpart and add the code there.
- If you still have problems and need help writing JSLink, use this super awesome tool by Andrey Markeev which will automatically list the webpart you want to add the code to, along with associating the file to that webpart when you create it: [Cisar](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cisar/nifbdojdggkboiifaklkamfpjcmgafpo)

Comment: With Cisar it's working. GREAT extension !!!

Comment: I tried a very early release of Cisar, couldn't get to work. Installed it again.. best thing since sliced bread!

Answer (score 1):

Doing double work :-\

I also copy/pasted your code and it worked fine.

As I needed a more generic version for any (internal) FieldName I rewrote it to:

```
(function () {
    var percentCompleteFiledContext = {
        Templates: {
            Fields: {
                "PercentComplete": {
                    "View": percentFieldTemplate,
                    "DisplayForm": percentFieldTemplate,
                    "NewForm": percentFieldTemplate,
                    "EditForm": percentFieldTemplate
                }
            }
        }
    };

    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(percentCompleteFiledContext);
})();

function percentFieldTemplate(ctx) {
    var H, percentComplete = parseInt(ctx.CurrentItem[ctx.CurrentFieldSchema.Name]);
    if ([1,4].indexOf(ctx.ControlMode) !== -1) { //DisplayForm(1) or View(4)
        H = "<div style='background-color:#e5e5e5;width:100px;display:inline-block;position:relative'>";
        H += "<div style='width:{1}%;background-color:#0094ff;'>&nbsp;</div>";
        H += "<div style=position:absolute;top:0px;left:2px;font-weight:bold>{1} %</div>";
        H += "</div>";
    } else { //NewForm or EditForm
        var formCtx = SPClientTemplates.Utility.GetFormContextForCurrentField(ctx);
        formCtx.registerGetValueCallback(formCtx.fieldName, function () {
            return document.getElementById('inp' + formCtx.fieldName).value;
        });
        H = "<input type='range' id='inp{0}' name='inp{0}' min='0' max='100' oninput='out{0}.value=inp{0}.value' value='{{1}}' />";
        H += "<output name='out{0}' for='inp{0}' >{{1}}</output>%";
        H = String.format(H, formCtx.fieldName);
    }
    return String.format(H, 'replace {1} with:', percentComplete);
}
```

#### Update 1

I struggled with this an eventually found the default Microsoft code for a ProgressBar is only loaded in `DragDrop.js`

Thus for a **VIEW** only (unless you load DragDrop.js yourself) You can use:

```
H=SPProgressMeter.CreateMeter( parseInt(percentComplete) );
```

it returns HTML:

```
<div class="ms-progress-meter"><div class="ms-progress-meter-inner" style="width: 45%;"></div></div>
```