# Progress on document Status

Tags: document, status

Can anyone help with setting up a progress status on documents in a document library. I would love something similar to the attached.[image]

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to use a Calculated Column (*set to datatype=Number!!! to output HTML*)

```
=IF(NOT(OR([Task Status]="Not Started",[Task Status]="Completed"))
    , "<div style=""position:relative;width:100%;height:1.5em;border:1px solid grey;"">"
        &"<div style=""position:absolute;height:100%;text-align:left;"
             &"background-color:"&  [color]
             &";width:"&  [% Completed]  &"%;"">"
        &  [% Completed]
        &"%</div>"
      &"</div>"
    ,"")
```

Pros:

- Works in 2010/2013 in any **View** (not on Forms)
- No need for CSR files/JSlinks (2013)

Cons:

- Displays HTML code as text in Alerts, CQWP, Content & Struture View
- Adds this HTML for every ListItem (so not very mobile friendly)

#### The 2013 (CSR) Client Side Rendering way

See: [jslink on Tasks % Complete field](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/159319/jslink-on-tasks-complete-field/159396#159396)